# How to concatenate strings contingent on two conditions?

Tags: r, concatenation

My data are similar to the following dummy data:

```
> dummy <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
    10, 10), dob = structure(c(1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 
    7L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("1990-01-01", "1991-11-12", 
    "1998-12-12", "1999-09-09", "2000-07-28", "2001-04-05", "2002-02-02", 
    "2004-12-16", "2012-05-06"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("2000-01-01", 
    "2000-01-03", "2002-12-15", "2003-01-06", "2003-04-05", "2003-12-15", 
    "2009-07-28", "2009-09-09", "2011-11-11", "2012-01-03", "2012-12-19", 
    "2012-12-31"), class = "factor"), text = structure(c(6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("2aabb", 
    "2ccdd", "2eeff", "2gghh", "2iijj", "aa bb cc", "dd ee ff", "ghi", 
    "jklm", "nop", "qq rr", "sss ttt", "uv", "www xxx", "yy zz"), class = "factor"), 
        gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("f", "m", "mnx"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
    "dob", "date", "text", "gender"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
> dummy
   id        dob       date     text gender
1   1 1990-01-01 2003-01-06 aa bb cc      m
2   1 1990-01-01 2003-01-06 dd ee ff      m
3   2 2001-04-05 2012-12-19      ghi      f
4   2 2001-04-05 2012-12-19     jklm      f
5   2 2001-04-05 2012-12-31      nop      f
6   3 1998-12-12 2000-01-01    qq rr      m
7   4 2012-05-06 2000-01-03  sss ttt      f
8   5 1991-11-12 2012-01-03       uv    mnx
9   6 2000-07-28 2009-09-09  www xxx    mnx
10  7 2002-02-02 2011-11-11    yy zz      m
11  8 1999-09-09 2009-07-28    2aabb      m
12  9 2004-12-16 2003-04-05    2ccdd      f
13 10 2001-04-05 2002-12-15    2eeff      m
14 10 2001-04-05 2002-12-15    2gghh    mnx
15 10 2001-04-05 2003-12-15    2iijj    mnx
```

My goal is to end up with a data frame that retains all of the columns, but where there are multiple rows that have the same date within an id, I need the strings in 'text' for those matching dates to be concatenated with a space between, such that each date within each id appears only once.  Here is what my goal data would look like:

```
dummy2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10), 
    dob = structure(c(1L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 
    6L, 6L), .Label = c("1990-01-01", "1991-11-12", "1998-12-12", 
    "1999-09-09", "2000-07-28", "2001-04-05", "2002-02-02", "2004-12-16", 
    "2012-05-06"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(4L, 
    11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("2000-01-01", 
    "2000-01-03", "2002-12-15", "2003-01-06", "2003-04-05", "2003-12-15", 
    "2009-07-28", "2009-09-09", "2011-11-11", "2012-01-03", "2012-12-19", 
    "2012-12-31"), class = "factor"), text = structure(c(5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2aabb", 
    "2ccdd", "2eeff 2gghh", "2iijj", "aa bb cc dd ee ff", "ghi jklm", 
    "nop", "qq rr", "sss ttt", "uv", "www xxx", "yy zz"), class = "factor"), 
    gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("f", "m", "mnx"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
    "dob", "date", "text", "gender"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
> dummy2
   id        dob       date              text gender
1   1 1990-01-01 2003-01-06 aa bb cc dd ee ff      m
2   2 2001-04-05 2012-12-19          ghi jklm      f
3   2 2001-04-05 2012-12-31               nop      f
4   3 1998-12-12 2000-01-01             qq rr      m
5   4 2012-05-06 2000-01-03           sss ttt      f
6   5 1991-11-12 2012-01-03                uv    mnx
7   6 2000-07-28 2009-09-09           www xxx    mnx
8   7 2002-02-02 2011-11-11             yy zz      m
9   8 1999-09-09 2009-07-28             2aabb      m
10  9 2004-12-16 2003-04-05             2ccdd      f
11 10 2001-04-05 2002-12-15       2eeff 2gghh    mnx
12 10 2001-04-05 2003-12-15             2iijj    mnx
```

I have tried:

```
dummy$text <- as.character(dummy$text)
test1 <- ddply(dummy, .(id, date), summarise, 
               paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(text, split=", "))), collapse=", "))

for (i in 1:length(dummy$id)){
  ifelse(dummy$id[i]==dummy$id[i-1],
  (ifelse(dummy$date[i]==dummy$date[i-1],textcon[i]<-     paste(dummy$text[i],dummy$text[i-1]),textcon[i]<-dummy$text[i])),
              (textcon[i]<-dummy$text[i]))
}
test3<-data.frame(dummy,textcon)
```

And many other variants, but I'm just not sure how to come up with the data where any date within an id is not duplicated!  This is similar to a couple of previous questions on SO except that my problem revolves around having to use two grouping factors concurrently, not one.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>%
   group_by(id, dob, date, gender) %>%
   summarise(text=paste(text, collapse=' ')) %>%
   select(id:date, text, gender)
```

or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dummy)
dummy[, list(text=paste(text, collapse=" ")), list(id, dob, date, gender)]
```

you can add `setcolorder` to `data.table` if order of the columns is important.

Comment: That's a lovely simple answer, thanks zero232